# How do the new "Assets" and "Flaws" affect Arena scoring?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

The range of Arena score you'll get in Fire Emblem Heroes (FEH) is based on--among other things--each of your team member's "BST," or the sum of all of the unit's stats with no skills equipped.

These are grouped in buckets of 5, so a BST of 170-174 would score the same, but 175 would score higher.

However, since there are "superboons" and "superbanes"--natures that give units +/-4 to a stat instead of 3--a unit's BST can increase or decrease by 1. Meaning the same unit can sometimes be 174 or 175 BST, which is a big deal.

With the introduction of Version 3.2.0, when merging a unit, they'll lose their bane, meaning they gain +3-4 in stats in addition to the usual merge stats.

Does this affect the BST that's used to calculate Arena score?

For example, if I have a (normally) 175 BST unit that has a superbane, so they're actually 174 BST for me and I merge them once so they lose the superbane, will they score like a 170 BST unit? Or a 175 BST unit?